# Conditional ROW NUMBER to create a Column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I have two columns ID and FLAG as :

```
ID  FLAG
1   Y
1   N
1   Y
1   N
1   N
1   N
1   N
1   Y
1   N
2   N
2   Y
2   N
2   N
2   Y
2   Y
2   N
```

**Required Output:**

```
ID  FLAG    REQ_COL 
1   Y       null
1   N       1
1   Y       null
1   N       1
1   N       2
1   N       3
1   N       4
1   Y       null
1   N       1
2   N       null
2   Y       null
2   N       1
2   N       2
2   Y       null
2   Y       null
2   N       1
```

**Logic for required column :**

1. For first occurence of ID , REQ_COL is null
2. If FLAG=Y then REQ_COL is null
3. IF previous value of FLAG is Y and there are consecutive N in FLAG , then the REQ_COL values are 1,2,3,4, 5.....
4. Else Null

I am trying to apply conditional row_number but not getting idea how to proceed.
Please help.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the stuff that what you're trying to apply...

Comment: What do "first occurence" _[sic]_ and "previous value" mean? The rows in a table have no order and you don't appear to have a column that provides a meaningful order.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you the result you are searching for...

Data Preparation

```
DECLARE @SOURCE_TABLE AS TABLE (realid int identity (1,1), ID int, FLAG CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @SOURCE_TABLE (ID, FLAG)
VALUES (1, 'Y'),(1, 'N'),(1, 'Y'),(1, 'N'),(1, 'N'),(1, 'N'),
       (1, 'N'),(1, 'Y'),(1, 'N'),(2, 'N'),(2, 'Y'),(2, 'N'),
       (2, 'N'),(2, 'Y'),(2, 'Y'),(2, 'N')
```

Actual Select

```
SELECT ST2.ID, ST2.FLAG,
NULLIF(NULLIF (CHARINDEX('Y', REVERSE(
(
    SELECT ST1.FLAG AS [text()]
    FROM @SOURCE_TABLE ST1
    WHERE ST1.ID = ST2.ID AND ST1.realid <= ST2.realid
    ORDER BY ST1.realid
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
)), 1) - 1, -1) AS [REQ_COL]
FROM @SOURCE_TABLE AS ST2
ORDER BY ST2.realid
```